# How to execute C# file which have Interface

Tags: c#

I have a text (code.txt) file which inherit interface

```
public class TablePrinting : ITable 
{

    public void Table()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This Is Table Method!!!!!");
            Console.WriteLine("Dynamic Binding Is Successful !!!");

        }
}
```

and i also write a code VS 2013

```
namespace DemoTablePrinting
{

    class Program
    {
        interface ITable
    {
        void Table();
    } 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 


            string Content =File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Asif\Desktop\code.txt");
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            CompilerParameters parameter = new CompilerParameters();
            parameter.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            parameter.GenerateInMemory = false;
            parameter.GenerateExecutable = true;

            CompilerResults result =provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameter, Content);
            if (result.Errors.Count > 0)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Errors building\n\n {0} into {1} ",Content, result.PathToAssembly);
                foreach (CompilerError ce in result.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  {0}", ce.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Source\n\r {0} built successfully.",Content);
            }
            Assembly assembly = result.CompiledAssembly;
            Type type = assembly.GetType("hello.TablePrinting");

            Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
    }
}
```

but it gives a compile error and and execption ITable file not found 
 Now How Can  i call all the the method of text file using interface

Comment: Your code.txt file won't compile because ITable isn't referenced in a using statement - it's declared in Program. I suggest moving the interface from there into code.txt

Comment: it is a small program if i not use interface then program run successfully. But if i want use interface in our program then it is not possible?

Comment: @ASIFHUSAINJafri In your project, add the code in code.txt as a .cs file and try compiling it - fix the error by my previous suggestion and then have that code to be the code in code.txt and it should work.

Answer (score -2):

You've defined your interface `ITable` inside `Program`. If you do this, you'll need to refer to it as `Program.ITable`, or include `Using Program` in the file where you define 'TablePrinting'.

If ITable isn't specific to `Program`, you should move the interface outside of the class.

You can nest classes but it's usually only done when you want to imply that the inner object is linked to the outer one.